# What is the performance impact of Views/large nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some very complicated stats queries that pull information from many different tables.

I created a view so that I am not running a similar GIANT query in my code over and over again. I am curious if this view will negatively impact my performance in the long run.

Basically I have two queries:

```
SELECT `columns` FROM statsTable
**complicated query....
WHERE user_id=10
```

VS

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT `columns` FROM statsTable
**complicated query....
) view
WHERE view.user_id=10
```

This is my understanding of how a view works.

Here is the difference in EXPLAIN for the above two queries:

### [image: explain1]

[image: explain2]

It looks the second query isn't indexing it very well. Do I need to ditch the view?

Comment: Does the data really need to be real time?  Could the views be materialized (or in mySQL[their table incarnation of it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)) say every 4,8,12, or 24 hours in which case you could index the materialized view?  if you can this would likely be the easiest to access and improve performance instead of getting the data on demand every time.

Comment: @xQbert The data table is already aggregated by date if that's what you mean. So the structure is `user_id`,`date`,`earnings`,`clicks`,`other columns...` with a unique  constraint on `user_id` and `date`. I am not sure how to "index a materialized view" - where can I read more about that?

Comment: http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views.  Basically take the view store it in a table and then add indexes.  Every so often you rebuild the table with more relevant/current data.  A view has to run all the joins generate the aggregates EVERY time you call it.  Having the data on Disk so to speak means those calculations are already complete and thus you're just querying a table.    or perhaps: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86790/best-way-to-create-a-materialized-view-in-mysql to keep it in the stack network.